# Finding edges that are not part of any perfect matching

Tags: algorithms, graph-theory

Given a balanced bipartite graph, what is, or is there, an efficient algorithm for finding all edges which are not part of any perfect matching in the graph?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your task can be solved in almost the same time as finding just one perfect matching.

Let *G*=(*V*, *W*; *E*) be a bipartite graph with |*V*|=|*W*|.  First, find one perfect matching.  As Henning Makholm noted, if there is no perfect matching, all edges satisfy the condition.

If there is a perfect matching *M*⊆*E*, then consider a directed graph by giving the orientation to each edge of *G* from the endpoint in *V* to the endpoing in *W*.  Also add the edge in the opposite direction for each edge in *M*.  Call this directed graph *G*′.  Decompose *G*′ into strongly connected components.  Now we can prove the following claim (whose proof is left as a fun exercise):

**Claim**.  An edge *v**w*∈*E* is used in some perfect matching in *G* if and only if *v* and *w* belong to the same strongly connected component of *G*′.

By using this, we can list all the edges that are not part of any perfect matchings in *G* by finding one perfect matching and performing the strongly connected component decomposition.  The latter takes time O(|*V*|+|*E*|).  The former takes time $\mathrm{O}(\sqrt{|V|}\,|E|)$ if we use the Hopcroft–Karp algorithm, as noted by Henning Makholm.  In total, it takes time $\mathrm{O}(\sqrt{|V|}\,|E|)$, assuming that |*E*|≥|*V*|.

Answer (score 3):

You can [test for the existence of a perfect matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopcroft-Karp_algorithm) in the original graph $O(E\sqrt{V})$ time. If there is none, all edges qualify.

Then, for each edge you can test whether there is a perfect matching that includes that edge simply by removing both endpoints (and adjacent edges) and see whether the remaining graph has a perfect matching.

These combine to an $O(E^2\sqrt{V})$ algorithm. Whether you consider that efficient is up to temperament, I suppose.